# OpenCV Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, osx-mavericks, homebrew

before this gets flagged as a repeat question please read the end. Thanks for looking.

I set up openCV using home-brew.

These were the commands I used:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```

I am using the following simple file I found online to test my set up:

```
// Example showing how to read and write images
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    // Load an image from file - change this based on your image name
    Mat img = imread("my_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    if(img.empty())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to load input image\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // this is just to show, that you won't have to pre-alloc
    // result-images with c++ any more..
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Write the image to a file with a different name,
    // using a different image format -- .png instead of .jpg
    if( ! imwrite("my_image_copy.png", img) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to write image file\n");
    }

    // no need to release anything with c++ !   
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I am getting after trying to compile and run suing `g++ test.cpp -o test`.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::destroyWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::waitKey(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in test-41a30e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did find similar issues on stack overflow but none using homebrew and I'm not sure how time- sensitive (with regards to updates and changes to OpenCV, my OS etc) the problem is. I'm using a mac with the 10.9.4 OS. Also those answers weren't really clear to me what should be changed. Many just suggested one line of code without saying where the line should go. I'm extremely novice with these technologies. Any help would be great thanks!

Edit:
Mark Setchell helped with the first batch of errors. But I am now getting: 
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test & ./Test

[3] 7187
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include/./Test
  Reason: image not found
[2]   Done                    g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test
Trace/BPT trap: 5

brewdoctor gave me this warning:
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

```
opencv
```

So I ran  brew link --overwrite opencv but got this:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9... 
Error: Could not symlink include/opencv/cv.h
```

needed the overwrite because brew link opencv gave

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9... 
Error: Could not symlink include/opencv/cv.h
Target /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
```

Comment: How did you try to compile it? What command?

Comment: @MarkSetchell with this: g++ test.cpp -o test. Thanks! Added that yo my question.

Comment: Try this... g++ @pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv@ test.cpp -o Test. Replace the @ signs with back ticks - near top left of keyboard.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I got this: clang: error: unsupported option '--cflags'
clang: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config'

Comment: I am having fun trying to input this, try this: g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test

Comment: Try `brew install pkg-config`

Comment: @MarkSetchell No errors on that! Thanks! No output though. I even added in a output line at the start of the main. It should be "... -o test" right? Not "Test"?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can call it `test` or `Test` - it's your program!

Answer (score 45):

You are getting linker errors. I think that is because you are not linking with the correct libraries that `opencv` requires.

The easiest way to get the correct libraries is with `pkg-config`, so I would recommend:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Then you may have to reinstall opencv

```
brew reinstall opencv
```

or maybe

```
brew uninstall opencv
brew install opencv
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test
```

You can run

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4
```

to see what it outputs for the `g++` compiler if you are interested - it tells the compiler where the libraries and header files are. On my system, it outputs this:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4

-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/include/opencv \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/include \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib \
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

If you are unfamiliar with `pkgconfig`, you can ask it to tell you all the packages it knows about like this:

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

My system gives output like this:

```
libzmq                              libzmq - 0MQ c++ library
gio-unix-2.0                        GIO unix specific APIs - unix specific headers for glib I/O library
glibmm-2.4                          glibmm - C++ wrapper for GLib
libpostproc                         libpostproc - FFmpeg postprocessing library
libgsf-1                            libgsf-1 - A library for reading and writing structured files (eg MS OLE and Zip)
gobject-introspection-no-export-1.0 gobject-introspection - GObject Introspection
libtasn1                            libtasn1 - Library for ASN.1 and DER manipulation
libusb-1.0                          libusb-1.0 - C API for USB device access from Linux, Mac OS X, Windows and OpenBSD/NetBSD userspace
gio-2.0                             GIO - glib I/O library
libusb                              libusb - USB access library (libusb-1.0 compat wrapper)
libecpg_compat                      libecpg_compat - PostgreSQL libecpg_compat library
QtNetwork                           Qtnetwork - Qtnetwork Library
opencv4                              OpenCV - Open Source Computer Vision Library
```

Basically, the first word in each line of the list above tells you the names of the packages `pkgconfig` knows about and that is the name you should specify when running commands such as

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4
```

If your system is a bit messed up, you can find the `.pc` file that `pkgconfig` uses like this:

```
find /usr/local/Cellar -name \*.pc
```

or

```
find /usr/local/Cellar -name \*.pc | grep -i opencv

/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

And then use the config file directly, like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

If it all compiles correctly, you can run it with

```
./test
```

Comment: You may be running `/bin/test`. Make sure you run `./Test` or `./test`

Comment: Hmm Seems to work for the most part. Getting this: g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test & ./Test
[3] 7187
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include/./Test
  Reason: image not found
[2]   Done                    g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test
Trace/BPT trap: 5 .


There is a picture there though in the same directory as this file.

Comment: Easy way to see the picture on OSX, is to type `open imagename`. e.g. `open my_image_copy.png`

Comment: I presume you have a `my_image.jpg` lying around in that directory for it to open?

Comment: Yes thanks so much for your help I have to leave right now. So I wont be able to work on this more right now.

Comment: @Bren So, did you run `rm /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h` and try again? Is it all working now?

Comment: Brilliant!  Followed Mark's suggestion of:  g++ @pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv@ test.cpp -o Test. Replacing the @ signs with back ticks - near top left of keyboard.

Answer (score 15):

You are getting these errors because you are using *OpenCV* methods in your code that are not linked to your project.

So far you have only included:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

But to run your code you need far more then these two *OpenCV* libraries. For example let's take the following error when trying to Build your project in XCODE:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

which corresponds to this part of your error:

```
...  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-41a30e.o  ...
```

This occurs because XCODE is looking to execute the following function in your code:

```
Mat img = imread("my_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

but the way you've implemented this, it doesn't know what **imread()** is, because the reference to the *opencv* library is missing! the Library that solves this particular problem is:

**libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.0.dylib**

(Of course the version depends on whatever version of *OpenCV* you are using.)

To resolve this particular error you have to do 2 steps:

1. Add the library to your project:
   Right-click on your project file. Click on "Add files to blabla" and then browse to your OpenCV directory. The libraries should be located in

`/Users/YOURNAME/YOURFOLDER/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib`

Caution! This could depend on how you've installed OpenCV! If you have installed it using Homebrew.The directory shoulb be here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib
```

[image: Picture: Add library to OpenCV Project.]

Select the following library (libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.0.dylib) and add it to your project:

[image: Picture: Pick the OpenCV Library]

After you have added the Library to your Project it should appear in the list on the left. **Double Check that you've picked the right library. Some of them have quite similar names!**

2. Include the Library in your C++ File

As you've done it with:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

You should now go on and include the new Library as well:

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"
```

[image: Picture: Include the new OpenCV Library]

3. Run your program

When you build your program again, you should have one error less. And XCODE shouldn't have a problem to run  **cv::imread**.

As you have plenty of errors, you should now go on by checking which libraries you need to successfully build your program.

I would recommend to Link these libraries as they are very common:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"
```

Before going crazy over all the errors you could just link all the libraries and see if it builds correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that brew compiled and linked with Xcode, and I was using a different version of g++ from macports. I just added the Xcode g++ location to my `$PATH` variable in my `.bash_profile` file and unlinked the wrong g++ binary with `sudo port select --set gcc none`. You can find the Xcode g++ location by running `xcodebuild -find g++`, mine was `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++`.