# Compiling hello world with opencv c++ on mac os x sierra

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

First time I cannot compile hello world.
I've followed tons of tutorials how to install opencv.
I just have following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat imageMe = imread("test.jpg", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

from opencv website.
Looks straightforward, but it won't compile.

```
g++ display_image.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -l
```

Here's the error:

```
display_image.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

And running:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

return this:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -l
```

these files are present.

Running `ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv2/core | grep core.hpp`
Gives the result:

```
core.hpp
```

What's the problem?

edit:
I've been using following tutorials to install opencv on my machine:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-on-yosemite-osx-10-10-x/

https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/

http://seeb0h.github.io/howto/howto-install-homebrew-python-opencv-osx-el-capitan/

edit:

Even after all these answers I cannot compile a single app. Even if it somehow can find .hpp file directly included in my file it fails finding includes inside.

Probably my configuration is wrong. 
In /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3 I have 2 directories:
3.2.0 - probably installed binaries
HEAD-9053839 - compiled from source

Now I also have opencv.pc file located in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:

```
prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0       
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: opencv
Description: The opencv library
Version: 2.x.x
Cflags: -I${includedir}/opencv -I${includedir}/opencv2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -l
```

As a prefix I've also tried HEAD-9053839.

I've created even simplier example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(){return 0; }
```

It's still telling me that 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found.
Then I printed what pkg-config says:
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -l
```

And found out it'd rather should be directly include dir, not opencv/opencv2 subdirectories.

So I've ran g++ like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -l display_image.cpp
```

Then it told me:

```
ld: library not found for -lopencv_contrib
```

After removing it it said:

```
ld: library not found for -lopencv_legacy
```

Then I had to remove -l before display_image.cpp, but then I've got another error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in display_image-9d8f86.o
      cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&) in display_image-9d8f86.o
```

This is hell.

Comment: I usually always put `-I directives` before specifying the source file, I always thought order is meaningful, could you try?

Comment: You used `opencv2`  as refix in your includes... Delete it.

Comment: Replace the 2nd and 3rd lines with `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` in OpenCV 3.x

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a compilation environment to regenerate your error but I think the problem is about these lines in your code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

since the opencv directory is being searched from

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv2
```

as your "pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv" implies. So, I suppose, changing the include lines into

```
#include <core/core.hpp>
#include <highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

would help, or you can implicitly declare the directory you want to search like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include display_image.cpp ...
```

Comment: Considering that vast majority of OpenCV code has includes in the form `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`, this looks like some issue with `pkg-config`. As such, I'd prefer your second approach (or even better, figure out what's up with `pkg-config` and fix that).

Comment: In file included from display_image.cpp:2:
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48:10: fatal error: 
      'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found

Comment: Well, it seems like there is something wrong with your pkg-config. Include statements are not complex as you may think. Try to locate the library using a terminal and check if you really have core.hpp over there. If not, you should check your opencv installation. If you have the correct libraries, then it means you're not telling the compiler correctly where to check.

Answer (score 2):

In **OpenCV 3.x**, the layout of the header files has changed and now you pretty much just use:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

So, in concrete terms, I am suggesting you replace your 2nd and 3rd lines with the above incantation.

See the [OpenCV Transition Guide](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html).

Comment: Affirmed also for Opencv 4. In the header file `opencv.hpp`, they just include all other header files. So theoretically, no need to include other OpenCV header files.

Answer (score 0):

Soner's answer should solve the OP's problem. I want to add some other solutions.

If you use CMake to install openCV from source, it will put OpenCV libraries in `/usr/local/lib` and OpenCV headers in `/usr/local/include`. Where the headers all go in the subfolder `/usr/local/include/opencv`. Since they are default library and header directories for most IDE's, all the examples you find will work with that config.

Now, `brew` does not install OpenCV to the above folders as you already knew. So you have three options:

1. Change compiler's search paths for OpenCV libraries and headers: `g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib`
2. Soft link `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include/opencv` to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib` to `/usr/local/lib`
3. Install OpenCV from source with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!
It was a problem with pkg-config.
In `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib/pkgconfig` I've found opencv.pc, which looks like this:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 3.2.0
Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
Libs.private: -framework OpenCL -L/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib -ljpeg -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -ltiff -lImath -lIlmImf -lIex -lHalf -lIlmThread -L/usr/lib -lz -framework Cocoa -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -framework Accelerate
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

I've replaced old opencv.pc located in: `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
Now I'm not getting any errors.

I also had to use different include file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Comment: After this I still had errors.  I needed to follow Mark Setchell's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985713/opencv-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error

Comment: brew install pkg-config .   then brew reinstall opencv . then pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv to see whats there . then g++ @pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv@ display_image.cpp -o display_image (note replace @ w/ back ticks top left of keyboard).

Comment: after  the #include of opencv2/opencv.hpp, the above install of pkg-config, re-install of opencv, and correct loading of libraries using pkg-config, I was successful.